# Can I Use Git Init Twice or Will It Override?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am creating a new project, essentially an iOS project (XCode) that I want to manage on BitBucket. I originally had a repository set up for Android, and after running "git init" in my iOS project directory, I am worried I am overlapping in some aspects of the version control. Did I set this up correctly?

Comment: So far as I know, the code and the history is kept the same. The hooks will be rewritten. But if you haven't changed the hook template between the two inits, they just keep the same.

Answer (score 2):

`git init` inside (or targeting) an existing Git repo will just make sure the repo is properly configured:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /path/to/repo/.git/
```

If you didn't get a warning like this, it's likely that you have now initialized two separate Git repositories. If they should be managed together, you could bring their histories together with `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`.

---

**Update:** To make sure you only have one Git repo, try this:

```
find /path/to/repo -type d -name .git
```

If everything is configured correctly, you should only get one result:

```
/path/to/repo/.git
```

If you don't get an entry like that, your Git repos were initialized in the wrong place. You should delete any stray `.git/` directories you see and try a `git init` only when `cd`'d to `/path/to/repo`.

Comment: I did get that warning, I am assuming that is alright as well? I essentially screwed it up and I want to remove all version control from the project (on my machine) and restart all over. It was much easier in Android with the terminal in Android Studio.